# Getting the array index in a foreach loop

Tags: php

So I may just be completely overcomplicating this for myself but I am trying to get the index of an array in a multidimensional array.

Hopefully showing it makes more sense.

```
Array
(
    [1234] => Array
        (
            [Name]  => Test
        )
    [5435]  => Array
        (
            [Name]  => Test
        )
)
```

I have a large array with different numbers as the index and I need to do a foreach through them, but I need that index number. (1234,5435)

Is there any easy way of doing this?

Comment: what is the criteria to select 1234,5435?

Comment: come on. it is in the manual on the most top part! [foreach](http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Glad you have found StackOverflow, Scott, and you did write a formal good question. But really, this is something that you could have found with a quick search on google, here, or php.net

Comment: Honestly I knew how to do ($arr as $key=>$val) but I just completely overcomplicated the situation for myself and didn't think it all the way though and feel like an idiot now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is.

```
foreach ($arr as $key=>$val)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

The `$key` is the key you need

Comment: Anytime, happy to help!